# Fit Q Evaluation in offline reinforcement learning

Tags: neural-networks, reinforcement-learning, deep-rl, off-policy-methods, offline-reinforcement-learning

I am working on a PyTorch implementation of Implicit Q-Learning (IQL) ([paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.06169)), given a dataset $\mathcal D = \left\{ (\mathbf s_i, \mathbf a_i, \mathbf s_i', r_i ) \right\}$ of transitions. I think I have implemented IQL correctly, so now I have a learned policy $\pi$ that takes in an element of the state space $\mathcal S$, and outputs a mean vector and covariance diagonals for a multivariate normal distribution over the action space $\mathcal A = \mathbb R^d$. I would like to evaluate this learned policy $\pi$.

This leads me to investigate off-policy evaluation, specifically Fit Q Evaluation (FQE), given a test dataset of transitions $\mathcal D_e$ as above. I have been reading the offline reinforcement learning paper by Prudencio et al. ([link](https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.01387)). **My problem is that I do not understand how to implement FQE as described in the paper, so I would appreciate guidance for this.** Below I quote the relevant part of the paper and ask some questions.

> ***C. Fit Q Evaluation***
>
> In fit Q evaluation (FQE), we first train a $Q$-function $Q_{\phi}^{\pi}$ by minimizing the Bellman error under the policy $\pi$. Then, we evaluate the policy by computing the average expected return over the states and actions from $\mathcal D_e$, such that
> \begin{align*}
> \hat J(\pi) = \mathbb E_{\mathbf s, \mathbf a \sim \mathcal D_e} \left[ Q_{\phi}^{\pi}(\mathbf s, \mathbf a) \right].
> \end{align*}

**Questions:**

1. Presumably I should use a neural network for $Q_{\phi}^{\pi}$, right?
2. What is the Bellman error in this context? I have some course notes that give a definition of the Bellman error involving $\max_{\mathbf a'}$, which is not workable since my action space $\mathcal A$ is $\mathbb R^d$ for some $d \in \mathbb Z$.

I have looked at the off-policy evaluation paper by Voloshin et al. ([link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06854)), which seems to describe FQE in a different way. Specifically,

> $\hat Q(\cdot, \theta) = \lim_{k \to \infty} \hat Q_k$, where
> \begin{align*}
> \hat Q_k &= \min_{\theta} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i = 1}^N \sum_{t = 0}^{\tilde T} \left( \hat Q_{k - 1}(x_t^i, a_t^i ; \theta) - y_t^i \right)^2\\
> y_t^i &\equiv r_t^i + \gamma \mathbb E_{\pi_e} \hat Q_{k - 1}(x_{t + 1}^i, \cdot ; \theta)
> \end{align*}

If I understand this correctly, we fit a sequence of neural network $Q$ functions $\hat Q_1, \hat Q_2, \dots$ here, trying to minimize the trajectory-average squared distance between $\hat Q_{k - 1}(x_t^i, a_t^i ; \theta)$ and $y_t^i$. But how do I calculate $y_t^i$ here? I don't know what $\mathbb E_{\pi_e} \hat Q_{k - 1}(x_{t + 1}^i, \cdot ; \theta)$ means.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Bellman error in general is the MSE error between your estimate of $Q(s, \pi(s))$ and your target, e.g. $r + \gamma Q(s', \pi(s'))$ (keeping notation simple here for how we obtain actions from policy). Your notes probably use a max because it will have been introduced in the context of Q-learning.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the original paper? See algorithm 3.

[Batch Policy Learning under Constraints](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.08738)

Here is an implementation I found: https://github.com/clvoloshin/COBS/blob/master/ope/algos/fqe.py
See their OPE paper for details: http://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06854